# Get the string from a value by using its pretty printer

Tags: types, ocaml

I have already coded lots of pretty printers of type `out_channel -> 'a -> unit`, now I would like a piece of code to get the string from a value by using its pretty printer.

For instance, I have already implemented the following functions:

```
type t =
  { x: int;
    y: int }

let co = { x = 4; y = 5 }

let print (chan: out_channel) (co: t) : unit =
  Printf.fprintf chan "(%d, %d)" co.x co.y
```

I think the function `Printf.sprintf` may help me to get the string `(4, 5)`. I tried `Printf.sprintf "%a" print co`, it gave me an error at the place of `print`: `This expression has type out_channel -> t -> unit but an expression was expected of type unit -> 'a -> string`.

Does anyone know how to remind this line, or does anyone have a solution other than `sprintf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For type-checking reasons, it's not possible to directly use `%a` in a formatting directive for sprintf.
If you can afford to use `Format` instead of `Printf`, things will be a lot easier:

- if you use OCaml 4.01, you directly have a `Format.asprintf` that, according to the documentation, does what you want.
- if you have an earlier version, it is easy to emulate this behavior by using a temporary buffer from which you create a formatter. You can then write to this formatter, and once your finished, you just have to retrieve the content of the buffer.

In fact, you have to use `Format.kfprintf` so that you can use an arbitrary formatting function:

```
  let sfprintf fmt =
    let b = Buffer.create 20 in
    let return fmt = Format.pp_print_flush fmt (); Buffer.contents b in
    Format.kfprintf return (Format.formatter_of_buffer b) fmt

  let s = sfprintf "%a" print co
```

The same technique could apply to `Printf` formatting functions, but there is another issue here: there's no way to create an `out_channel` out of a `Buffer.t`. The closest way I can think of is to rely on the `pipe` function of the `Unix` module:

```
let sfprintf fmt =
  let (infd,outfd) = Unix.pipe () in
  let inc = Unix.in_channel_of_descr infd in
  Unix.set_nonblock infd;
  let outc = Unix.out_channel_of_descr outfd in
  let return outc =
    Printf.fprintf outc "%!";
    let b = Buffer.create 10 in
    try
      while true do 
        Buffer.add_char b (input_char inc) done;
      assert false;     
    with Sys_blocked_io -> 
      Unix.close outfd; Unix.close infd; Buffer.contents b
  in
  Printf.kfprintf return outc fmt;;

let s = sfprintf "%a" print co
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I don't clearly understand what you need, so let me guess:

```
let prints (co: t) : string =
  Printf.sprintf "(%d, %d)" co.x co.y

let print ch co = Printf.fprintf ch "%s" (prints co)

# print stdout co;;
(4, 5)- : unit = ()
```

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. If somebody will do what you want -- I really want to see the result.